# bigger resolution in JMF

Tags: java, jmf

Hi there guys i got this code in leejava but its only save jpg file with size 320x240 i want it to capture and save with bigger resolution starting at least at 800x600.
Can anyone help me??

the code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.media.*;
    import javax.media.format.*;
    import javax.media.util.*;
    import javax.media.control.*;
    import javax.media.protocol.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*;
    public class SwingCapture extends Panel implements ActionListener
    {
    public static Player player = null;
    public CaptureDeviceInfo di = null;
    public MediaLocator ml = null;
    public JButton capture = null;
    public Buffer buf = null;
    public Image img = null;
    public VideoFormat vf = null;
    public BufferToImage btoi = null;
    public ImagePanel imgpanel = null;
    public SwingCapture()
    {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(320,550);
    imgpanel = new ImagePanel();
    capture = new JButton("Capture");
    capture.addActionListener(this);
    String str1 = "vfw:Logitech USB Video Camera:0";
    String str2 = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";
    di = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(str2);
    ml = di.getLocator();
    try
    {
    player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
    player.start();
    Component comp;
    if ((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null)
    {
    add(comp,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    add(capture,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(imgpanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Frame f = new Frame("SwingCapture");
    SwingCapture cf = new SwingCapture();
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    playerclose();
    System.exit(0);}});
    f.add("Center",cf);
    f.pack();
    f.setSize(new Dimension(320,550));
    f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void playerclose()
    {
    player.close();
    player.deallocate();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
    if (c == capture)
    {
    // Grab a frame
    FrameGrabbingControl fgc = (FrameGrabbingControl)
    player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
    buf = fgc.grabFrame();
    // Convert it to an image
    btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());
    img = btoi.createImage(buf);
    // show the image
    imgpanel.setImage(img);
    // save image
    saveJPG(img,"c:\\test.jpg");
    }
    }
    class ImagePanel extends Panel
    {
    public Image myimg = null;
    public ImagePanel()
    {
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(320,240);
    }
    public void setImage(Image img)
    {
    this.myimg = img;
    repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
    if (myimg != null)
    {
    g.drawImage(myimg, 0, 0, this);
    }
    }
    }
    public static void saveJPG(Image img, String s)
    {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(img, null, null);
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
    out = new FileOutputStream(s);
    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException io)
    {
    System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
    JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bi);
    param.setQuality(0.5f,false);
    encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
    try
    {
    encoder.encode(bi);
    out.close();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException io)
    {
    System.out.println("IOException");
    }
    }
    }
```